# Running into a type error when trying to sort()

Tags: python

Function

```
def sort_contacts(contactlist, column):
    if column == 0:
        contactlist.sort(key=lambda l: str(column[0]))
        return contactlist
    else:
        contactlist.sort(key=lambda l: str(column[1]))
    return contactlist
```

How I am calling it in main

```
elif option == '5':
        contact_list = contacts.sort_contacts(contact_list, 0)
    elif option == '6':
        contact_list = contacts.sort_contacts(contact_list, 1)
```

The error presented is *TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
but the original question is to use column to sort by first name which would [0] and last name [1] but I am kinda bamboozled at this point and need guidance that I can't seem to get.

Comment: If each element in `contactlist` is a list, then I think you meant `l[0]` and `l[1]` instead `column[0]` and `column[1]` as `column` is integer. Better if you provide content of `contactlist` in the question

Comment: You pass an integer to sort_contacts (column) which you then try to subscript. The integer class doesn't implement \_\_getitem__ (mainly because it wouldn't make sense) hence the TypeError

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `column == 0`
Which means that column is an int, but you can't use slice on int ( therefore you can't do `column[0]`

It's where your error is, but we'd need to see more of the code for a complete answer, for instance what is contact_list

If I had to guess what you wanna do is

```
contactlist.sort(key=lambda l: str(contactlist[column]))
```

but that's just a supposition